# `'%` breaks hyperlinks in Markdown preview

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

`'%` breaks hyperlinks in Markdown preview. [Example](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/28585/1832):

[image]

The link works once the edit is saved:

[image]

---

Experiment below:

[https://example.com/an'%20example](https://example.com/an%27%20example)

Comment: I think it's actually the apostrophe in the URL that's causing that one to break. Removing the apostrophe causes `chairs` to be included in the link. (...Which might just be correct/expected behavior per the CommonMark spec; I'm not sure.)

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, good point. Note that the link works once the edit is saved.

Comment: I also noticed that when the apostrophe is removed, `%20` becomes a space in the preview but not in the final post.